# How do I encode booleans using yason?

Tags: json, encoding, common-lisp

I'm trying to use the [`yason`](http://hanshuebner.github.io/yason/) library to encode some data for an API endpoint. Some parts of the return value here are going to be booleans. The problem is

```
cl-user> (yason:encode nil)
null
NIL
cl-user>
```

According to their docs, there is [a flag named `*parse-json-booleans-as-symbols*`](http://hanshuebner.github.io/yason/#*parse-json-booleans-as-symbols*), but there doesn't seem to be an inverse for encoding. (And the appropriate symbols don't seem to auto-encode appropriately).

```
cl-user> (yason:encode 'true)
"true" ;; expected `true` rather than `"true"`
"true"
cl-user> (yason:encode 'false)
"false" ;; expected `false` rather than `"false"`
"false"
cl-user>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but note that **nil** is the canonical false value in Common Lisp, but also used for lots of other things.  The symbol **t** is the canonical true value, even though any-non nil value will is also a true value. The examples from the YASON documentation show that **t** is serialized as the JSON true literal:

> ```
> CL-USER> (yason:encode
>           (list (alexandria:plist-hash-table
>                  '("foo" 1 "bar" (7 8 9))
>                  :test #'equal)
>                 2 3 4
>                 '(5 6 7)
>                 t nil)
>           *standard-output*)
> [{"foo":1,"bar":[7,8,9]},2,3,4,[5,6,7],true,null]
> (#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 2 {59942D21}> 2 3 4 (5 6 7) T NIL)
> ```

If **null** is treated as a false value by the JSON consumer, the standard behavior with **t** and **nil** may be sufficient for your use.

As another option, you could map your false booleans (i.e., **nil** when used as a boolean) to **yason:false** in advance.  The symbols **yason:true** and **yason:false** map to the booleans as you'd expect:

```
CL-USER> (yason:encode t)
true
;=> T

CL-USER> (yason:encode nil)
null
;=> NIL

CL-USER> (yason:encode 'yason:true)
true
;=> YASON:TRUE

CL-USER> (yason:encode 'yason:false)
false
;=> YASON:FALSE
```

If you're interested in how I discovered this (I've never used YASON before), I installed YASON with Quicklisp, and then using Slime inspected **yason:encode**.  I discovered that it's a generic function with a number of methods defined:

```
  (DEFGENERIC YASON:ENCODE (YASON::OBJECT &OPTIONAL STREAM))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE (EQL ()))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE (EQL T))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE (EQL NULL))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE (EQL YASON:FALSE))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE (EQL YASON:TRUE))
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE LIST)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE VECTOR)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE HASH-TABLE)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE INTEGER)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE FLOAT)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE RATIO)
  (DEFMETHOD YASON:ENCODE STRING)
```

You can inspect the source of these individually, but the source of the methods on **(eql ())** (i.e., **(eql NIL)**), and of **(eql YASON:FALSE)** were the important ones.

Comment: I'm looking to implement the Common Lisp version of [this](http://todobackend.com/specs/index.html?http://todo-backend-sinatra.herokuapp.com/todos), which demands `false` in a particular object sub-field, so I'll have to use `yason:false` in the appropriate place.

Comment: @Inaimathi Depending on what that object is, of course, you could also define a method for that object type that serializes it directly.  Then you could still use the conventional values within the Common Lisp code.